# Get new command line args while running

Tags: vb.net

i'm running a vb.net app that uses command line args and store them in variables, and, for example, put them in a textbox. I want another external app to pass data every minute to my app by calling my app with the data as argument.
I know I can get the command line arguments using GetCommandLineArgs. But can I get 'new' args while running, whithout restarting the app?

Example:
- I start the app, using "myapp.exe argument1". This shows "argument1" in the textbox
- Next, I run "myapp.exe argument2" (while myapp.exe is still running), and so myapp should just keep on running, but now display "argument2"

Is this possible using command line args, or do I need to use another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> But can I get 'new' args while running, whithout restarting the app?

No, command line arguments are only set once during the lifetime of a running application. You will need to use another approach to pass the data to your application (WCF, sockets, database, files, remoting, named pipes, ...).